# Periodic failure when editing or creating in SQL using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem which I can't really figure out. I am tranfering information from a form, via JSON, to a PHP file which is handling the database call.
When trying it on my apache server it works aprox 75% of the time. The last 25% nothing happens. The form-window will close as ment to, and the page will reload, but the information hasn't been put into the DB. 
When trying it at my domain, nothing happens at all. Same code though (I have another DB_connection file, with domain info, which works other places).

I'd like to have my code reviewed, to see if I have made a major mistake. Would love to have it 100% working. 
As I said I have both a creation and an edit. I will post the edit form + php content here. If you need to see the creation, please tell me.

Javascript function, called when pushing the edit key (a test will be performed on the form fields before):

```
function xmlHTTPEdit() {
    var product_ID = document.forms["addForm"]["product_ID"].value;
    var product_Name = document.forms["addForm"]["product_Name"].value;
    var product_Price = parseInt(document.forms["addForm"]["product_Price"].value);
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "../db/productEdit.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("createID=" + product_ID + "&createName=" + product_Name + "&createPrice=" + product_Price);
}
```

My php-file, updating DB, using the new data:

```
<?php
    include('DB_Connect.php');

    $product_ID = trim($_POST['createID']);
    $product_Name = trim($_POST['createName']);
    $product_Price = trim($_POST['createPrice']);

    $sql = "UPDATE products SET productName = '$product_Name', productPrice = '$product_Price' WHERE productID = '$product_ID'";

    mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

I really hope some of you can help me finding this flaw in my code and maybe help me with an explanation, why it works sometimes at localhost and never at my domain.

Thanks.
/Pyracell

Comment: You have made a major mistake.  Please meet [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: If you are talking about prepared statements and/or sql injections it will be changed. At the moment I'd prefere some help to fix this problem. I see no reason in security, while running it at apache + my own domain for testing :) and btw. I wrote I was testing before my javascript call. Maybe I did the injection test there?

Comment: I'm not seeing the use of JSON at all here.  Nothing more than an observation.  Other than such observation this is as simple as it gets really the only issues that can be occurring check to make sure your form fields are correct, check your data to ensure there is always a row that meets that criteria, and ensure that your database is up/connection is correct while doing the update.

Comment: @JStead, you are right sry. My brain has mixed the code :) There's no JSON in this part. Just normal POST.
Just before this javascript function is called, another function, testing the fields is run to test. And the database is up'n'running all the time. Using Xampp for apache + sql handling. And when using my domain the database is 24h running. Is the rest of the code ok?

Comment: I suppose the same data fails 25% of the time?

Comment: @le dorfier, not really. I've tried having a failure at a certain data, and then try it again afterwards, with success :/ which is the reason for my frustration

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it works sometimes makes me think there's something MySQL is unhappy about. Since PHP no longer throws MySQL errors as exceptions, you'll need to manually fetch the error.

Calling and echoing `[mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) immediately after the query will display any resulting error, though a more appropriate solution for production would be to have it log to file rather than output to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the data to a file rather than the database. Ajax is less solid than a database connection. I'd look there first. But isolate the two from each other for testing.